# Integrate Single Page application into WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have lots of basic single page applications which have html, css, js files  I would like to publish them on wordpress.

I can add them like external website but when I used this, I have to add all static parts (header, menu, footer etc) to the app.html file. And I have to do this for each application. This is not sustainable and good solution for sure. This is why I am looking for some way to add this page after menu in wp like other pages.

I would like to give you folder hierarchy to concrete the problem.

> - || - apps
> - || - || - app1
> - || - || - || - app1.html
> - || - || - || - app1.js
> - || - || - || - app1.css
> - || - || - || - img
> - || - || - || - || - img11.png
> - || - || - || - || - img12.png

---

> - || - || - app2
> - || - || - || - app2.html
> - || - || - || - app2.js
> - || - || - || - app2.css
> - || - || - || - img
> - || - || - || - || - img21.png
> - || - || - || - || - img22.png

I would like to add apps folder to the wp and create pages by using admin panel if it is possible.

I tried this (to add only one app), it calls html but js and css didnt work. (js and css files were linked inside html files)

```
<?php /* Template Name: App1 */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include 'apps/app1/app1.html'?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

**edit:** When I directly integrated css & js codes to html file internally, the system works properly. However when I tried to add them externally the system doesnt work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app1.css">
<script src="app1.js"></script>
```

When I inspected codes (CTRL + Shift + I) I saw the problem, how can I fix this path ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app1.css">
```

Comment: The browser console should give information about the files that are not loading and what address the browser is searching

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `..` to indicate the parent directory:

Try this

```
<?php /* Template Name: App1 */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include '../apps/app1/app1.html'?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Much probably it's a path issue but OP didn't mention the directory his apps reside, your solution assumes it's on `wp-content/themes/apps` :)

Comment: There is not any problem with path. '../apps/app1/app1.html' doesnt work, 'apps/app1/app1.html' this path works. However the problem is, js and css files that were linked inside this html does not work while html is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Install **apps** folder directly inside **wp-content** folder

Inside .html file, I changed this;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app1.css">
<script src="app1.js"></script>
```

With this;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/apps/app1/app1.css">
<script src="/wp-content/apps/app1/app1.js"></script>
```

And Php file

```
<?php /* Template Name: App1 */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php include 'wp-content/apps/app1/app1.html">'; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This solves the problem however still I am not sure whether this is reasonable solution from maintenance point of view.